# Recursive definitions of scanl and scanr in Haskell

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, fold

I have searched but cannot find simple definitions of the functions `scanr` and `scanl`, only explanations that they show the intermediate calculations of the functions `foldr` and `foldl` (respectively).

I have written a recursive definition for `scanl`, based on the `foldl` property `foldl f y (x:xs) = foldl f (f y x) xs`:

```
scanl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
scanl' f x [] = [x]
scanl' f x (y:ys) = x : scanl' f (f x y) ys
```

This seems to work. However, there is a type error when I try to apply this analogy with the `foldr` property `foldr f y (x:xs) = f x (foldr f y xs)`:

```
scanr' :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
scanr' _ x [] = [x]
scanr' f x (y:ys) = y : f x (scanr' f x ys)
```

This fails as the second input for `f` needs to be a `b` not a `[b]`. However, I am unsure how to do this while also recursing on `scanr'`.

Comment: Are you sure it should not be `scanl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]`?

Comment: Yep, sorry - I accidentally copied an old version of the code I wrote.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: @AJFarmar How is `scanr` defined? (Or at least, how can it be defined recursively?)

Comment: @A.Morris I found this, the actual implementation, in less than a minute using hoogle: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#scanr

Comment: @AJFarmar so did I but I understood neither the syntax nor how the definition could be derived (whereas with Fred Miller's answer I now think I understand both).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute

```
result = scanr' f x (y:ys)
```

you must have computed

```
partialResult = scanr' f x ys
```

after which you get

```
result = (y `f` head partialResult) : partialResult
```

The complete implementation is

```
scanr' _ x [] = [x]
scanr' f x (y:ys) = (y `f` head partialResult) : partialResult
    where partialResult = scanr' f x ys
```

Answer (score 0):

scanl1 (\acc x -> if x > acc then x else acc)[3,4,5,3,7,9,2,1]

from *Learn You A Haskell* seems to have only two arguments: the function and the list. Yet it works. It even works if you write it as:

scanl1 (\x acc -> if x > acc then x else acc)[3,4,5,3,7,9,2,1]

Slightly puzzling why works.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It is an example, but I believe OP already had that available.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).